# Почему не вставляется текст в форму? Версия selenium 4.9.0

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://suip.biz/ru/?act=findomain")
xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/article[1]/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input'
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,xpath)
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys('example')
```

Answer (score 0):

я использовал сафари , так как у меня нет фаерфокс + нужно в настройках поставить галочку "Разрешить удаленную автоматизацию"

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get("https://suip.biz/ru/?act=findomain")
xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/article[1]/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input'
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  # установка времени ожидания в 10 секунд
elem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys('example')
time.sleep(10)  # задержка в 10 секунд перед закрытием окна
driver.quit()  # закрытие окна
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас в коде только одна ошибка, смотрите что вам пишут в ошибках:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Происходит это, потому что синтаксис у вас где-то потерялся. Тут два варианта есть:

- использовать [`.find_element()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html?highlight=find_element#selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element), тут вроде всё хорошо, но `By.XPATH` — это не функция, поэтому необходимо передавать так:
  `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)`
  Т.е. передаём **как ищем** и **что** ищем через запятую. Можно не импортировать `By.XPATH`, т.к. это всего лишь словарь, а вместо него написать `'xpath'`, но лучше так не делать.
- но можно также использовать `.find_element_by_xpath()`, тогда получится
  `driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)`

В остальном код вполне рабочий. Никогда не забывайте смотреть что вам выводится в ошибках.

Comment: Ну тут конкретно дело не в коде. Тут я ошибся, когда залил, но с другими сайтами проблемы заполнения форм не возникает. А именно этот сайт не хочет вообще ничего принимать. Я исправил в find_elemеnt параметры, но так и не заработало.

Comment: @Djapa ну как не в коде… тогда стоит указывать версию Selenium, у меня после исправления всё отлично.

Comment: Версия селениума 4.9.0

Comment: Ну вот документация по API тоже 4.9, не могло `.find_element(By.XPATH(xpath))` запуститься без ошибок. На Firefox исправленный код работает без проблем.